# What is the minimum value of voltage and current that HSPICE can measure?

Tags: hspice

I am using HSPICE for my simulations. I want to make sure HSPICE is measuring the minimum value of current and voltage correctly. What are those values?
How can I set them?

Comment: If you don't trust a simulator, best not use it. Else, the generic SPICE variables that deal with tolerance, and are named in the form of `*tol` (`reltol`, `abstol`, etc), each dealing with specific tasks. But even that is not enough, because it also matters what quantities you are measuring. For example you shouldn't expect uA precision for MA quantities; you might be lucky, you might not. All these are generic SPICE limitations, I don't know how HSPICE deals with them, in particular -- though I'm fairly sure it, too, obeys such restrictions.

Comment: Look for RELTOL, and read the manual. By the way, none of the SPICES do "measurements'. All the values are computed, using many many steps of matrix-math convergence, and if any reactive components are used --- either lumped L or C, or in device models --- then complex math is also used to describe any phaseshifts, further muddying the computed-results origin

Comment: SPICE uses floating-point arithmetic, so a more important issue is the dynamic range of values in your simulation. What are the maximum voltage/current in your simulation and what resolution of voltage/current do you need?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, whether you can get uA precision on a MA current is exactly what the `reltol` parameter determines. If you set `reltol` below 1e-12, you should indeed get microamp precision on a megamp value. (assuming you don't hit the limits of the floating point precision, which may well be single-precision, first)

Comment: @ThePhoton While I agree with what you said, I have to point out that the default value is `0.0025` (in LTspice at least, in some `0.007`, others `0.001`, etc), and it's like that for good reasons. Nobody says you can't change it and, but you'd better stock up on half or so of the world's coffee. :-) What I wanted to imply in my comment (and, apparently, failed) was that OP didn't say what is that minimum OP expects, so it's difficult to say, precisely, what to change.